# Can anyone explain me this regex meaning

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to understand this expression meaning.

```
$req_msg =~ s/ \${$toReplace}/$replacements->{$toReplace}/g;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $req_msg =~ s/ \${$toReplace}/$replacements->{$toReplace}/g;

s is used for substitution. `$content=~ s/old_value/new_value/modifier;`  (modifier can be i, g, x, along or combination)

Ex:

```
$content = "Hi I am a coder and I like coding very much!";
$content =~ s/i/eye/i;
```

now $content will contain "Heye eye am a coders and eye like coding very much"

In the same way ${$toReplace} which simply means a scalar reference is the old value which needs to be replace and $replacements->{$toReplace} means $replacements is a hash reference whose key is $toReplace .
It is smiliar to $hash_value = hash_ref->{key};

whereever it finds the value returned by scalar reference , gets replace by hash reference's key  with the corresponding value  found in $req_msg

But I guess you asked this question because you got blank replacement. That may be due to scalar reference problem.

This code snippet may help in removing your doubt.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $value = "Jassi";
my $scalar_ref = \$value;

print "scalar_ref = $scalar_ref \n and value = $value and ${$scalar_ref}\n";
my %hash = ("Jassi", "aliencoders");
my $hash_ref = \%hash;
my $reg_msg = "Hi this is Jassi";
print "reg_msg = $reg_msg \n";
$reg_msg =~ s/${$scalar_ref}/$hash_ref->{${$scalar_ref}}/;
print "reg_msg after s = $reg_msg\n";
```

**See the second last line!**

Answer (score 4):

Prerequisite for this to work are two variables:

- `$toReplace` - contains an arbitrary value
- `$replacements` - a HASH ref containing, erm, replacements

Given `$toReplace` contains "foo", the contents of `$req_msq` are searched for `${foo}` (with a leading single space) with every occurence of this being replaced with `$replacements->{foo}`.

Comment: I think it would be looking for `${foo}`, not `$foo`.

Answer (score 0):

It replaces every occurance of the text `${blabla}` with whatever is stored in the hash reference `$replacements` with the key `blabla`, e.g.:

```
$replacements = { 'blabla' => 'blubb' };
```

will make every `${blabla}` being replaced by `blubb` in `$req_msg`.